# Google Cloud Tasks - Network Error on create multiples tasks

Tags: node.js, google-tasks

In this code below I have a client which creates multiples tasks inside a map loop. However, this process doesn't complete and returns the follow network error:

> Error: request to https://cloudtasks.googleapis.com/$rpc/google.cloud.tasks.v2.CloudTasks/CreateTask failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

How can I fix this?

```
const { CloudTasksClient } = require('@google-cloud/tasks');

exports.sendTask = (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body.data;
    const client = new CloudTasksClient({ fallback: true });
    const parent = client.queuePath(process.env.PROJECT, process.env.LOCATION, process.env.QUEUE);
    const url = process.env.URL;
    let counter = 0;
    data.map(payload => {
        counter += 1;
        console.log('preparando task ', counter);
        const task = {
            httpRequest: {
                httpMethod: 'POST',
                url,
                oidcToken: {
                    serviceAccountEmail: process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: Buffer.from(payload).toString('base64')
            }
        };
        client.createTask({parent, task});
        console.log('Task gerada.');
    });
    res.status(200).send();
}
```

[Exception from task creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESxw5.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks) - `client.createTask` is async function, means, your code should wait for it's result somehow. Having a loop here, I guess, you want call all of them asynchronously, not one by one, and wait for result of all of them. I suggest you to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
const { CloudTasksClient } = require('@google-cloud/tasks');

exports.sendTask = async (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body.data;
    const client = new CloudTasksClient({ fallback: true });
    const parent = client.queuePath(process.env.PROJECT, process.env.LOCATION, process.env.QUEUE);
    const url = process.env.URL;
    let counter = 0;
    await Promise.all(data.map(payload => {
        counter += 1;
        console.log('preparando task ', counter);
        const task = {
            httpRequest: {
                httpMethod: 'POST',
                url,
                oidcToken: {
                    serviceAccountEmail: process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: Buffer.from(payload).toString('base64')
            }
        };
        console.log('Task gerada.');
        return client.createTask({parent, task});
    }));
    console.log('All task were generated.');
    res.status(200).send();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Alex Shtromberg. We try the promise, but the problem continues.

Comment: @RodrigoC.Martins pay attantion that you have to put `return` by the end of your map function: return `client.createTask({parent, task});`

Comment: We did this, but the problem remains. When we try a few items, it works fine, but with 15 items, some do fine, but some return error, with many, like 80 all items return error.